# Group of GTK radio buttons does not work properly

Tags: c, gtk

I have created a group of radio button in a grouplist and attached callback to the buttons. The code is as per below:

Function for callback:

```
void set_game_level(GtkWidget *widget,gpointer user_data){
g_print("testing toggle");
}
```

Function display setting:

```
GSList *group;
GtkWidget * levelButton;
levelButton = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label (NULL, "Easy");
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox2), levelButton);
group = gtk_radio_button_group (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (levelButton));
levelButton = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(gtk_radio_button_group (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (levelButton)),
             "Medium");
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox2), levelButton);
levelButton = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label(gtk_radio_button_group (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (levelButton)),
             "Hard");
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (vbox2), levelButton);

gtk_signal_connect_object (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (levelButton), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(set_game_level),NULL);
```

The result is not as per what expected. I would assume that whenever i click on one of the radio button it will fire up the callback but it seems that sometimes button "Easy" is fire up sometimes button "hard" is fire up. The fire event somehow i can say is inconsistent. Is my implementation incorrect or missing anything or toggle only work on 2 widget or 2 states.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `grp = gtk_radio_button_get_group(btn1);` on your first radio button to retrieve a group. For all other buttons you want to share one `marking` use `gtk_radio_button_set_grp (btn234_n, grp);`

---

From docbook:

> When an unselected button in the group is clicked the clicked button
>   receives the "toggled" signal, as does the previously selected button.
>   Inside the "toggled" handler, gtk_toggle_button_get_active() can be
>   used to determine if the button has been selected or deselected.

Comment: Thanks @drahnr, will try the suggestion.